# Can the AWS Glue script be modified while an instance is running

Tags: aws-glue

This is more of general question for which I am not able to find an answer for.

1. Can the AWS Glue script be modified while an instance id running.
2. Will the editing of the script affect the the execution of the first instance. Like, Will the first instance continue its execution with copy of the older code. or will the first instance use the new version of the code.

This issue occurs when more than one developer shares a glue job to execute their scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a Glue ETL job, it performs the following operations in the specified order

1. Launch the requested number of DPUs at the backend
2. Download the ETL script from the S3 path.
3. Execute the ETL script in a Spark environment using the spark-submit command

Thus, to answer your questions,

1. Yes, you can edit the script of a Glue job while the job is performing its JobRun
2. No, it will not affect the execution of already running instances of the job

Comment: oh. okay. Thank you. :)